# Assign HKLM/HKCU to a variable for different types of installs

Tags: nsis

I'm writing a script to associate file associations, and I'm wondering if it's possible to assign a variable to HKLM or HKCU depending on whether it's an admin or user install. The project I'm working on determines this at run time when the user appends `-user` for a user install as opposed to an admin install. I was thinking of something like:

```
Var location
${If} $InstallMode == "Admin"
    $location = HKLM ;probably not the right way to assign
${Else}
    $location = HKCU
${EndIf}
```

I'm new to NSIS and from what I've read and tried so far, I can `!define` a variable to be `HKLM` or `HKCU` by writing `!define location HKCU` but define won't work during runtime.

Comment: Registry roots cannot be variables unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHCTX` exists for this purpose. It is controlled by `SetShellVarContext`. The default is the user (`HKCU`), set to `All` for `HKLM`.